# How can I tell Java that two "?"s are the same type?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I am currently getting a compile error on this line:

```
chosenState = chosenState.withProperty(property, value);
```

in which `property` is an `IProperty<?>` and value is a `Comparable<?>`. The signature of `withProperty` is:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> IBlockState withProperty(IProperty<T> property, V value);
```

and the type arguments of `IProperty` are:

```
IProperty<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

The compile error is:

```
chosenState = chosenState.withProperty(property, value);
                         ^
required: IProperty<T>,V
found: IProperty<CAP#1>,Comparable<CAP#2>
reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
  equality constraints: CAP#1
  lower bounds: V,Comparable<CAP#2>
where T,V are type-variables:
  T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T,V>withProperty(IProperty<T>,V)
  V extends T declared in method <T,V>withProperty(IProperty<T>,V)
where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
  CAP#1 extends Comparable<CAP#1> from capture of ?
  CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

I would like to solve it by finding types `T` and `V`, where:

- `IProperty<?>` extends `IProperty<T>`
- `Comparable<?>` extends `V` extends `T` extends `Comparable<T>`

Some type parameters that would work would be `<?, ?>`, but where both `?`s are unknown but the same type, or at least the first `?` extends the second. Is there any way to tell this to the compiler?

I know that the two `?`s are the same because `value` is an element of the collection returned by the `Collection<T> getAllowedValues();` method in `IProperty<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

I know that I could solve this by casting to `IProperty` and `Comparable`, but I would like to avoid using raw types.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Please show the implementations.

Comment: What are `property` and `value` originally, before the cast?

Comment: That looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I did show all the implementations. `property` is `IProperty<?>`, `value` is `Comparable<?>`, and I want to call `<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> IBlockState withProperty(IProperty<T> property, V value);` on them without the use of raw types.

Comment: why are you casting the two variables to `IProperty` and `Comparable` in the method call? `chosenState.withProperty((IProperty) property, (Comparable) value)`

Comment: @Onheiron: Sorry, I forgot to erase that when I copied the line. That's what I'm doing as a workaround right now, but I'd like it to work without having to cast them to their raw types.

Comment: how can you be sure that `Comparable<?>` is an extension of `IProperty<?>`?

Comment: @Onheiron: `value` is an element of the collection returned by the `Collection<T> getAllowedValues();` method in `IProperty<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Comment: I find it strange that OP accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431090). If I understand correctly we don't have specific types like `IProperty<String> property = ...; String value = ...;`, if we had them there wouldn't be need for casting in the first place. Instead we have `IProperty<?> property` (based on "`property` is an `IProperty<?>`") which would fail at `new Tuple<>(property, value)` so we are moving same problem to different part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assure the compiler that `V` is bound to `T`.

Using wildcards the compiler cannot guarantee that `Comparable<?>` is going to be subtype of `?` because you can have `String value` and `IProperty<Integer>` which are not compatible.

To solve your issue you can create intermediate wrapper that will hold `value` and `property` that guarantees `V extends T` restriction and keep reference to `Tuple<?, ?>` instance bounded by wildcards instead of individually with `property` and `value`:

```
    public class Tuple<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>{
        private IProperty<T> property = null;
        private V value = null;

        public Tuple(IProperty<T> property, V value){
            this.property = property;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public IProperty<T> getProperty() {
            return property;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    } 

   <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> IBlockState withProperty(Tuple<T, V> t){
        return withProperty( t.getProperty(), t.getValue() );
    }
```

And finally:

```
    IProperty<String> property = ...;
    String value = ...;

    Tuple<?, ?> t = new Tuple<>(property, value);

    withProperty(t);
```